# Как поймать нажатие клавишы без текстовой формы

Tags: события, javascript

Есть такой вопрос я знаю что у текстовых полей есть события `onkeypress` `onkeyup` и т.д а как сожно отлавливать события клавиш за пределами текстового поля (просто после загрузке страницы) я хочу сделать миниигру и мне надо чтобы функция выполнялась при нажатии например на левую стрелку без всяких там текстовых полей В IE неработает ничего из нижесказанного!

Comment: тоже самое событие надо повесить на тело страницы, а не на конкретное текстовое поле...

Comment: в IE и FIREFOX неработает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

Вот пример.

Comment: Офигеть! высший класс!

Comment: Аказывается в IE неработает! Чё делать в IE?

Comment: Вот оно как... А если повесить на document.body?

Comment: Если document.body то работает только в Opera а в Firefox и IE неработает (доэтого хоть в фаирфоксе работало)

Comment: и ещё: document.onkeydown работает абсолютно также как window.onkeydown (Везде кроме IE) 
НЕНАВИЖУ IE!!!fucked browser!

Answer (score 2):

воспользуйтесь плагином [jQuery shortKeys plug-in](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/shortkeys/)

Comment: о Боги, ну вот почему и тут пихать какие-то JQuery плагины?
Прямо под вашим ответом есть, посмотрите на пример @ling 'a и скажите мне - на кой тут плагин?

Comment: выбор - это всегда хорошо

Comment: А пример Ling неработает в IE!

Answer (score 0):

можно привязать обработчик события на любой элемент.это необязательно должно быть текстовое поле.можно также попробовать присвоить определенное значение объекту event,т.е.код клавиши.но за последнее не ручаюсь-это предположение,надо проверять.